# Consuming a RESTapi stream with angular2

Tags: angular

How is it possible to consume a "never-ending" data stream with angular2? I'm writing a little chat app with a server written in go and a client writting in angular2. For a push service I implemented an endpoint which will keep the connection up. A authorized user can connect to the message broker on `server.com:123/broker` with a GET request. Every time a new message for the user arrives its send to the broker in form of a json-object. How ever, when using the normale syntax I won't get any results (since the code waits for the connection to be closed as I suppose):

```
return this._http.request(req).map( (res: Response) => {    
    return res.json();
}).subscrube( results => {
    console.log("results arrived", results);
});
```

Consuming streams has a lot of advantages (like video streaming with a rest api, awesome). Is there a way to do this?

/edit: A little bit more information here:
I checked the http transaction and they look okay:

```
GET /broker HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: mydomain.com:12345
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer [JWT]
```

The server ansers with the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 11:16:45 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

[then the client is listening on this connection until the server pushes something into the stream

```
ba
{"target":"56addcef7bec6d5785ee6945","payload": ...}
```

Seems correct so far. I can see the size of the chunk in hex (ba), the CRLF, the payload (json) and the final CRLF. So, when talking about HTTP Standard everything seems okay. However, my Angular2 won't fetch the chunks.

Comment: Your code is just printing the results. Just assign it to a field in the component or add it to an array and bind the view to it.

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. As said, the connection is not closed and therefore the message _seems_ to be incomplete. What I want is to process data, when it arrived, not when the connection is closed. I used this package for the streaming: https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest#streaming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in one of the comments, this is currently not possible with Angular2 itself, a feature request is already documented (from 06/2015): check it out [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2795)

To get things working until the feature is implemented I now [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/) as an external API.

**Add dependency in `package.json`:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "oboe": "*",
     ...
},
```

*Don't forget to run `npm install` or to download the package etc.*

**Include oboe in `index.html`**

```
<script src="node_modules/oboe/dist/oboe-browser.min.js"></script>
```

**Use oboe to consume the http-stream**

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

// Declare oboe as a Variable
declare var oboe: any;

@Injectable()
export class BrokerService {
    private oboeService: any;
    constructor() {
        this.listen();
    }

    listen(): void {
        console.log("registering message broker")
        var config = {
            'url': 'https://you-streaming-api.com:123/broker',
            'method': "GET",          
            'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._jwToken },         
            'body': '',     
            'cached': false,
            'withCredentials': true            
        }            
        this.oboeService = oboe(config);            
        // The '!' will only consume complete json objects
        this.oboeService.node ('!', function (thing) {            
            console.log("new broker message", thing); 
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the responseType and Accept headers for video/mp4 in angular 5? Sorry if it sounded stupid, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: This discussion happened early 2019, Is any angular inbuilt or improved plugin available to achieve the same in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement a custom [backend](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1b0593ddfc69383d152a592a5e6faaa8647f0e1/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts) that forwards each event it receives individually instead of only the whole result.

This alternative backend can be registerd for DI to be used everywhere instead of the original one, or only when explicitely requested. The later would also need an alternative `Http` implementation to distinguish between default and streaming one because this type is the one actually injected into a component or service. The backend is only a transitive dependency requested by `Http`.

Comment: But I can't be the only one who wants to use streamed data with angular2? (because then I'm likely to have the wrong approach). Isn't angular2 all about reactive programming? Is there another approach to consume a server sided push service with angular2 I just missed?

Comment: Angular doesn't provide a `Http` implementation for Dart at all. They don't want to maintain all the additional features requested. This might be the same reason they don't provide a more sophisticated implementation for JS/TS. Maybe they expect the community to chime in and build an advanced `Http` replacement. `Http` just takes a URI (and optional arguments) and returns data. There is no coupling with Angular and this makes it a good candidate for a 3rd-party module. This is mostly speculation on my side. Just create a feature request if you think this should be supported.

Comment: There is already a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2795

Answer (score 0):

In my case `const oboe = require('oboe');` worked instead of `declare var oboe: any;`

Env: Ionic 5 with Angular 9

Updated code:

```
const oboe = require('oboe');   <<<---- Updated code

@Injectable()
export class BrokerService {
    private oboeService: any;
    constructor() {
        this.listen();
    }

    listen(): void {
        console.log("registering message broker")
        var config = {
            'url': 'https://you-streaming-api.com:123/broker',
            'method': "GET",          
            'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._jwToken },         
            'body': '',     
            'cached': false,
            'withCredentials': true            
        }            
        this.oboeService = oboe(config);            
        // The '!' will only consume complete json objects
        this.oboeService.node ('!', function (thing) {            
            console.log("new broker message", thing); 
    });
    }
}
```