# Read buffered response with Angular2/RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I'm building a website that reads data from a backend. That data is computed on-the-fly and sent back to the client in a buffered manner. I.e. as soon as the first chunk is computed it is sent to the client, then it computes the next chunk and sends that to the client. This whole process happens in the same HTTP request. The client should not wait for the complete response to finish but handle each chunk by its own as soon as has been sent. Such responses can usually be consumed using the XHR progress handler (e.g. [How to get progress from XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976/how-to-get-progress-from-xmlhttprequest)).

How can I consume such a response with the HttpModule in Angular2 using RxJS and Observables?

---

**Edit**: peeskillet gave an excellent and detailed answer below. In addition, I did some further digging and found a [feature request for the `HttpModule` of Angular](https://github.com/angular/http/issues/77) and a [StackOverflow question with another approach on how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115764/consuming-a-restapi-stream-with-angular2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:** The following answer is only a POC. It is meant to educate on the architecture of Http, and also provide a simple working POC implementation. One should take a look at the source for [`XHRConnection`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L37) for ideas on what else you should consider when implementing this.

When trying to implement this, I don't see any way to tap directly into the XHR. It seems maybe we need to just provide custom implementations of some of the components involved with using `Http`. The three main components that we should consider are

- `Connection`
- `ConnectionBackend`
- `Http`

`Http` takes a `ConnectionBackend` as a argument to its constructor. When a request is made, say with `get`, `Http` creates a connection with `ConnectionBackend.createConnection`, and returns the `Observable` property of `Connection` (that's returned from `createConnection`). In the most stripped down (simplified) view, it looks like this

```
class XHRConnection implements Connection {
  response: Observable<Response>;
  constructor( request, browserXhr) {
    this.response = new Observable((observer: Observer<Response>) => {
      let xhr = browserXhr.create();
      let onLoad = (..) => {
        observer.next(new Response(...));
      };
      xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    })
  }
}

class XHRBackend implements ConnectionBackend {
  constructor(private browserXhr) {}
  createConnection(request): XHRConnection {
    return new XHRConnection(request, this.broswerXhr).response;
  }
}

class Http {
  constructor(private backend: ConnectionBackend) {}

  get(url, options): Observable<Response> {
    return this.backend.createConnection(createRequest(url, options)).response;
  }
}
```

So knowing this architecture, we can try to implement something similar.

For the `Connection`, here is the POC. Imports left out for brevity, but for the most part, everything can be imported from `@angular/http`, and the `Observable/Observer` can be imported from `rxjs/{Type}`.

```
export class Chunk {
  data: string;
}

export class ChunkedXHRConnection implements Connection {
  request: Request;
  response: Observable<Response>;
  readyState: ReadyState;

  chunks: Observable<Chunk>;

  constructor(req: Request, browserXHR: BrowserXhr, baseResponseOptions?: ResponseOptions) {
    this.request = req;
    this.chunks = new Observable<Chunk>((chunkObserver: Observer<Chunk>) => {
      let _xhr: XMLHttpRequest = browserXHR.build();
      let previousLen = 0;
      let onProgress = (progress: ProgressEvent) => {
        let text = _xhr.responseText;
        text = text.substring(previousLen);
        chunkObserver.next({ data: text });
        previousLen += text.length;

        console.log(`chunk data: ${text}`);
      };
      _xhr.addEventListener('progress', onProgress);
      _xhr.open(RequestMethod[req.method].toUpperCase(), req.url);
      _xhr.send(this.request.getBody());
      return () => {
        _xhr.removeEventListener('progress', onProgress);
        _xhr.abort();
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Here's we are just subscribing to the XHR `progress` event. Since the `XHR.responseText` spews out the entire concatenated text, we just `substring` to get chunks, and emit each chuck through the `Observer`.

For the `XHRBackend`, we have the following (nothing spectacular). Again, everything can be imported from `@angular/http`;

```
@Injectable()
export class ChunkedXHRBackend implements ConnectionBackend {
  constructor(
      private _browserXHR: BrowserXhr, private _baseResponseOptions: ResponseOptions,
      private _xsrfStrategy: XSRFStrategy) {}

  createConnection(request: Request): ChunkedXHRConnection {
    this._xsrfStrategy.configureRequest(request);
    return new ChunkedXHRConnection(request, this._browserXHR, this._baseResponseOptions);
  }
}
```

For `Http`, we will extend it, adding a `getChunks` method. You can add more methods if you want.

```
@Injectable()
export class ChunkedHttp extends Http {
  constructor(protected backend: ChunkedXHRBackend, protected defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  getChunks(url, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Chunk> {
    return this.backend.createConnection(
       new Request(mergeOptions(this.defaultOptions, options, RequestMethod.Get, url))).chunks;
  }
}
```

The `mergeOptions` method can be found in the [`Http` source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L25).

Now we can create a module for it. Users should directly use `ChunkedHttp` instead of `Http`. But because to don't attempt to override the `Http` token, you can still use `Http` if you need to.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpModule ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ChunkedHttp,
      useFactory: (backend: ChunkedXHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new ChunkedHttp(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [ ChunkedXHRBackend, RequestOptions ]
    },
    ChunkedXHRBackend
  ]
})
export class ChunkedHttpModule {
}
```

We import the `HttpModule` because it provides other services that we need to be injected, but we don't want to have to reimplement those if we don't need to.

To test just import the `ChunkedHttpModule` into the `AppModule`. Also to test I used the following component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClick()">Click Me!</button>
    <h4 *ngFor="let chunk of chunks">{{ chunk }}</h4>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.style.css']
})
export class App {
  chunks: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: ChunkedHttp) {}

  onClick() {
    this.http.getChunks('http://localhost:8080/api/resource')
      .subscribe(chunk => this.chunks.push(chunk.data));
  }
}
```

I have a backend endpoint set up where it just spits out `"Message #x"` in 10 chunks every half a second. And this is the result

[image]

There seems to be a bug somewhere. There's only *nine* :-). I think it's server side related.

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer :) If you are interested, you might also have a look at the links I added to the question as I did some further digging.

Comment: Would you mind publishing this as a reusable module? it's probably a must have for heavy data angular apps.

Comment: This discussion happened early 2017, Is any angular inbuilt or plugin available to achieve the same in 2021?