# Angular2 track file upload progress with Http api

Tags: angular, file-security, x-xsrf-token

How to use angular2 HTTP API for tracking upload progress?

I can do it with native javascript XHR method. But XHR method does not provide XSRF protection whereas HTTP API provides XSRF protection by setting `XSRF_TOKEN` cookie.

I need both XSRF protection and file upload progress.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39820718/2587435)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use angular2 http API for tracking upload/download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231123/how-to-use-angular2-http-api-for-tracking-upload-download-progress)